# SQL Server Group By Aggregate Query on a One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 SQL SERVER Tables with One To Many Relationship

```
Table : Orders
---------------
BILL_NO    QUANTITY
100         1
101         2

Table : Mobility
----------------
MOBILITY_UID      BILL_NO           DATE        CURRENT_LOCATION
1                 101               20/07/18    1_NO-SHOP 
2                 101               21/07/18    2_NO_SHOP
3                 102               21/07/18    WORKSHOP
```

Now i need a  query to fetch which location has how much quantity of Orders based on last location update of the BILL (like 2_NO_SHOP is the last location for BILL no 101 as it was last updated with MOBILITY_UID = 2 )

Expected Result :

```
CURRENT_LOCATION   QUANTITY
1_NO_SHOP          0
2_NO_SHOP          2
WORKSHOP           1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1):

`outer apply` gets the quantities by location -- but not the zero ones.

```
select m.current_location, o.quantity
from orders o outer apply
     (select top (1) m.*
      from mobility m
      where m.bill_no = o.bill_no
      order by date desc
     ) m;
```

I am going to suggest:

```
select l.location, coalesce(mo.quantity, 0) as quantity
from (select distinct current_location as location from mobility) l left join
     (select m.current_location, o.quantity
      from orders o outer apply
           (select top (1) m.*
            from mobility m
            where m.bill_no = o.bill_no
            order by date desc
           ) m
     ) mo
     on mo.current_location = l.location
```

Another method uses `row_number()`:

```
select m.current_location,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then o.quantity else 0 end) as quantity
from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by m.bill_no order by m.date desc) as seqnum
      from mobility m
      order by date desc
     ) m left join
     orders o
     on m.bill_no = o.bill_no
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort , but none of this wroks ,first 2 queries not giving any aggregated result , it's showing a join result with all rows , last one not executing.

I made a function to get the last location of a order from mobility table , then used that function to fetch quantity and last location in same row , then used group by and sum , it's  working , see my answer below >>

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would do the trick ?

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_LOCATION
,   quantity 
FROM (
SELECT 
    M.CURRENT_LOCATION
,   CASE WHEN Bill_DATE = MAX(M.Bill_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY M.BILL_NO ORDER BY M.Bill_DATE DESC) THEN O.quantity ELSE 0 END  quantity
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M.BILL_NO ORDER BY M.Bill_DATE DESC) RN
FROM Mobility M
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.BILL_NO = M.BILL_NO
) D 
ORDER BY CURRENT_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getCurrentLocation', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION getCurrentLocation;  
GO  
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCurrentLocation(@BILLNO VARCHAR(10))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(20);  
    SELECT @ret = (SELECT TOP 1 CURRENT_LOCATION  
    FROM MOBILITY OM   
    WHERE OM.BILL_NO = @BILLNO  
          ORDER BY MOBILITY_UID DESC)
     IF (@ret IS NULL)   
        SET @ret = '';  
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Then used aggregated Query

```
SELECT DBO.getCurrentLocation(od.BILL_NO) AS LOCATION 
,sum(OD.QUANTITY) FROM ORDERS OD 
where DBO.getCurrentLocation(od.BILL_NO) <> '' 
group by  DBO.getCurrentLocation(od.BILL_NO)
```